# Changing a Meteor.Collection before parsing

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, collections, meteor

I have the following problem:
I'm retrieving a Meteor Collection from my Mongo database. This Collection shall be parsed into HTML via built in handlebar.js. Before that I want to either change a value in the Collection without saving it to the db or add a new value to the Collection without saving it.

This is because the inserted data depends on calculations which is done at runtime.

I tried te following:

```
var topics = Topic.find({}, {sort: {votes: -1}});
var totalUsers = Meteor.users.find({}).count();
topics.forEach(function(topic){
  var numberOfGoodVotes = topic.votes.goodVotes.length;
  var numberOfBadVotes = topic.votes.badVotes.length;
  topic.pctGood = (numberOfGoodVotes*(100/totalUsers));
  topic.pctBad = (numberOfBadVotes*(100/totalUsers));
  topic.pctRest = 100 - topic.pctGood - topic.pctBad;
});
```

Unfortunately pctGood/Bad/Rest are all 0 which cannot be possible. In this case pctGood/Bad/Rest are stores in my Collection and have the value 0. This is why I assume it is not changed after computation.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div style="width: {{pctGood}}%;">{{pctGood}}%</div>
<div style="width: {{pctRest}}%;">{{pctRest}}%</div>
<div style="width: {{pctBad}}%;">{{pctBad}}%</div>
```

Hope anyone can help :)

Comment: Side note: `numberOfGoodVotes` and `numberOfBadVotes` should be scoped inside that anonymous function. Right now they are global variables. Scope them like `var numberOfGoodVotes = ...` and `var numberOfBadVotes = ...`.

Comment: Thx, edited this. Unfortunetly doesn't solve the Problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a working solution. Just add a function to the transform option.

```
var topics = Topic.find({}, {sort: {votes: -1}, transform: YOURFUNCTIONGOESHERE});

var YOURFUNCTIONGOESHERE = function(topic){
  var totalUsers = Meteor.users.find({}).count();
  var numberOfGoodVotes = topic.votes.goodVotes.length;
  var numberOfBadVotes = topic.votes.badVotes.length;
  topic.pctGood = (numberOfGoodVotes*(100/totalUsers));
  topic.pctBad = (numberOfBadVotes*(100/totalUsers));
  topic.pctRest = 100 - topic.pctGood - topic.pctBad;
  return topic;
}
```